# How to use macros or any other way to add @Column and turn the below code into snake_case from camelCase?

Tags: macro, repeated-commands, filetype-java

Say that I have a java class with these fields(included only few fields, but the idea is that there could many more fields).

```java
public class Entity {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String costPrice;

    private String sellingPriceForSomeItem;
}
```

Now I need to convert the above code to below code:

```java
public class Entity {

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")    
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "cost_price")
    private String costPrice;

    @Column(name = "selling_price_for_some_item")
    private String sellingPriceForSomeItem;
}
```

Can we use macros to do this? Now in the above class, you see only 4 fields, but say that I have 100 such fields and I want to use some vi/vim way to speed up this process? How would one go about solving this? I am fine if we are unable to get the last field to work(i.e., fields with more than one camelCase word in it like sellingPriceForSomeItem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a substitution with a sub-replace-expression:

```
:%s/\ze\(\s*\)private \w\+ \(\w\+\)/\=submatch(1).'@Column(name="'.substitute(submatch(2), '\u', '_\l&', 'g').'");'."\r"
```

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h \zs
:h submatch()
:h substitute()
:h /\u
:h sub-replace-special
:h s/\l
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution

```
g/^\s*private/copy. | normal! -2dwdw"_C@Column(name = "^R=substitute(@-, '\(\l\)\(\u\)', '\1_\l\2', 'g')^M")
```

An explanation:

```
g/^\s*private/...           for all lines starting with "<spaces>private"
    copy. | normal! ...     make a copy of the current line then enter normal mode command
    -2dwdw"_C               up one line on first non-blank char; delete 2 words;
                            then delete one word putting it into register "minus";
                            then delete remaining part (i.e. semicolon)
                            and enter insert mode
    @Column(name = "^R=...^M") The new text with a computed part (note: ^R and ^M
                               must be entered as ^V^R and ^V^M respectively)
    substitute(@-, ...)     value of register "minus" from camelCase to snake_case
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd accept a solution that requires a Vim plug-in (specifically for the snake case coercion), then I could recommend one that involves recording a macro to process each line.

In particular, you would have to install plug-in [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish), which includes a [`cr`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/blob/7e4da6e78002344d499af9b6d8d5d6fcd7c92125/doc/abolish.txt#L146) operation to do case coersion, in particular `crs` (or equivalently `cr_`) for `snake_case`.

So you could record a macro to process a specific line with:

- <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>: Record macro `@q`.
- <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>: Yank current line and put it above the current line. This duplicates the current line and leaves you at the top line.
- <kbd>$</kbd>: Move to the end of the line, cursor will be on top of the `;`.
- <kbd>s</kbd> `")` <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Replace the `;` with a `")` which is what you want at the end of the line.
- <kbd>B</kbd>: Move to the start of the word, this should be the field name.
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>: This is the vim-abolish command to convert case to `snake_case`.
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> `@Column(name = "` <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Changes from the beginning of the line (`^`) until the beginning of the field name, and insert the `@Column` contents you wanted to insert.
- <kbd>q</kbd>: Stop recording the macro.

At this point, you can move the cursor to the next line (if you're using a search such as `/private` or `/String` then you can use `n`, actually `nn` to skip the current match; otherwise use a `3j` for three lines down, or a similar motion), then replay the macro using <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. The second time you repeat it, you can simply use <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>@</kbd>, which repeats the last macro that was executed (`@q` in this case.)

Or you can use a `:g` command as well:

```
:g/private/norm @q
```

This will execute the `@q` macro on every line that matches the `/private` search.